# fetch function returns promise instead of object

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a function `getData` in `functions.js`, when I called in another file, `scripts.js` it returns promise not an object.

```
//------ functions.js ------

export async function getData(arg1,arg2,arg3) {

...

let result = await fetch(proxyUrl + targetUrl, requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));

return result
    }
```

When I call like this I get a Promise:

```
//------ scripts.js ------

import {getData} from './functions';

let result = getData(arg1,arg2,arg3)
console.log(result)
```

But even I called like this, I get an Error:

```
//------ scripts.js ------

import {getData} from './functions';

let result = awiat getData(arg1,arg2,arg3)
console.log(result)
```

"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word"

Comment: You have a typo here `awiat` --> let result = awiat getData(arg1,arg2,arg3)

Comment: For the first snippet, it's expected, that result is not an object but a promise. And in the second, i expect `awiat` is just a typo? And if you have `await`, this is only allowed inside of an async function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getData` is a `async` functions and returns a `Promise` and [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) is only allowed inside `async` function.

```
export async function getData(arg1,arg2,arg3) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(proxyUrl + targetUrl, requestOptions)
    return await response.json()
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
    throw err
  }
}
```

```
import { getData } from './functions';

getData(arg1,arg2,arg3).then(result => {
  console.log(result)
})
```

OR this way

```
import { getData } from './functions';

const print = async () => {
  const result = await getData(arg1,arg2,arg3)
  console.log(result)
}

print()
```

Comment: Actually I don't want to print the object, I want to save it as an object. Here, I want to save the output of getData Function inside result. So I can use it later.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of explicitly promise-based code with `.then()` and `.catch()`, use a try/catch block and an actual `return` statement in an `async` function, :

```
export async function getData(proxyUrl, targetUrl, requestOptions) {
    try {
        let response = await fetch(proxyUrl + targetUrl, requestOptions);
        return response.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error', error);
    }
}
```

Of course this function *still* returns a Promise. Every `async` function does. Promises *never actually goes away*, `async`/`await` only hides them. It's syntactic sugar. This is important: **You cannot return a value from an asynchronous function**, no amount of syntactic sugar can change that fact.

So when you call it, either `await` it in another `async` function

```
async function main() { 
    var data = await getData(...);
}
```

or use Promise semantics in a regular function:

```
function main() { 
    getData(...).then(data => ...);
}
```

Comment: Actually I don't want to print the object, I want to save it as an object. Here, I want to save the output of getData Function inside result. So I can use it later.

Comment: @DSaad Not sure what you refer to. The code in my answer does not "print" the object. You haven't really read what I wrote.